# What does malloc(0) return a address instead of NULL? what does that address mean

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Why does

```
int *p; 
p= (int *) malloc(0);
printf ("%p", p);
```

print an address? Because logically its a **0 bytes of memory**, so what is that base address meaning to? (I mean the address stored in p).

*Kindly any well known dev in this topic, pls do reply to this query.

Comment: Because it can? The only thing you can do with that pointer is pass it to `free()` or `realloc()`, though. Can't dereference it.

Comment: Rather because someone without common sense designed the API, so it allows malloc to either return NULL or an address... Don't mistake the C standard lib for something carefully designed after some sort of rationale.